# how to get struct form binary file?

Tags: c, database, function, data-structures, struct

```
#include.... 
typedef struct node
{
    unsigned key ; 
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *head = NULL; 
void createnode(int data);// creating a linked list
int open_record(char *Filename);
void close_file(int file);
int insert_record(int File , node *rec);
int get_record(int File , node *rec , int key);
            
int main(void)
{
    
    int fb = open_record("data2");
    node *rec;
            
    for(int i  = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        createnode(i);
    }
               
    
    rec = head ;
    // copy the structs into fb bin file 
    while(rec->next != NULL){
        insert_record(fb,rec);
        rec = rec->next;
    }
    node getRec;
    //getting the structs from fb bin file 
    get_record(fb,&getRec,3);
    printf("%d",getRec.num);
    close_file(fb);
    return 0 ; 
}
     
int open_record(char *Filename)// opening the fb bin file 
{
    int file = open(Filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR |O_APPEND, 0644); 
    if(file == -1)
    {
        perror("open_record");
    }
    return file;
}

void close_file(int file)
{
    close(file);   
}
            
int insert_record(int File , node *rec)
{
    int ret ; 
    ret = write(File,rec , sizeof(node));
    return ret;  
}
```

this function where the problem is this function return 0 else ret return  0

```
int get_record(int File , node *rec , int key) // here where problem are 
{
    int ret = read(File,rec , sizeof(node)) ; 
    while(ret != -1)
    {
        if(ret == 0 ) 
        {
            memset(rec,0 ,sizeof(node));
            break;
            return ret;
        }else if(key == rec->num/*replace pf rec->key*/)
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }
    memset(rec,0 ,sizeof(node));
    return ret ;    
}
```

what i trying to do is a small database so the issue is i cannot access the struct that i saved in file fb . the function `get_record` return 0 and i don't know why. i think the read function can not find the fb file.

- how can I read from a binary file?
- how can I get the struct from the fb file?

Comment: After calling `insert_record` in a loop the `fp` points to the end of the file. You need to reopen the file or lseek back to the beginning of the file before trying to read the records.

Comment: "this function 0 the ret return olse 0" what? Please [edit] your post to make it legible.

Comment: What is `BinFile` for?

Comment: pointer of other binary file